# mlpack include file errors

Tags: c++, mlpack

Recently I am about to learn mlpack. Today I have successfully built the solution from mlpack source code, but when I newly create a project I get the following error in the header file. I would like to know what is wrong and how to fix it.

[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3g1f5.png)

In the screenshot, the `algorithm.hpp` is under the build folder and its absolute path is `D:\MLPack\mlpack\build\include\mlpack\core\std_backport\algorithm.hpp`. The source code in the new project is just a copy from `https://www.mlpack.org/`.

The screenshot below shows some of the files generated after building solution of `mlpack.sln`.

[generated libs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Huy8m.png)

The versions of other libraries to help build the mlpack are :

```
Armadillo      10.8.0 (at least 9.800)
Boost (math_c99, spirit) 1.78.0 (at least 1.58.0, and I have added this version string in  CMakeLists.txt before building mlpack)
CMake          3.20 (at least 3.6)
ensmallen      2.18.1 (at least 2.10.0)
cereal         1.3.0 (at least 1.1.2)
openBLAS       0.24.1
```

The configurations of my new project are shown below.

[additional include directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSG4I.png)

[additional dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAYmJ.png)

[post-build event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0fTX.png)

And I have also disabled "Conformance Mode".

[disabled conformance mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WOY5.png)

The entire building and using process refer to `https://www.mlpack.org/doc/stable/doxygen/build_windows.html` and `https://www.mlpack.org/doc/mlpack-3.4.2/doxygen/sample_ml_app.html`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found out that this problem seems to be related to the version of the source code. I should not use the latest version of the source code from `https://github.com/mlpack/mlpack`, but the source code corresponding to the latest **stable** version. After I replaced the include directory with the include directory corresponding to the officially released windows installation package, no error was reported during the building of the solution in my new project, so I got the expected result.

[the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZTss.png)

This incident taught me a lesson that I should use the stable rather than the latest version of the source code when doing CMake in the future.